Scripts to get, set and restore sound level
I want to adjust the Master sound level and later restore it. In a terminal I can use amixer to get and set the level. How can I incorporate these commands in a script? For example I have a background sound playing, I want fade it to run another procedure and then restore it to the original level.

"How can I incorporate these commands in a script?": What commands? What procedure? What scripting language? Please edit your question and give us some context.

What commands? amixer (amaster in the original question was a misprint which I have corrected.) amixer get Master ... amixer sset Master etc.  ... What language? Bash.

Please EDIT the question and include this since comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. And show us the exact commands you want to run. Show us what you have written so far and explain what part of it is giving you trouble (this site isn't for getting free scripts, but we are happy to help you write your script).
